# Ext.NET Partial view is not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ext.net

I have an application that shows a series of tabs. One such tab has a panel that I want to decompose into partial views. My main view looks like this:

```
@model MyModel
@{
    var x = Html.X();
}

@(x.Panel()
    .Layout(LayoutType.Fit)
    .Items(i =>
    {
        i.Add(new GridPanel
        {
            Region = Region.West,
            Layout = LayoutType.Fit.ToString(),
            Loader = x.ComponentLoader()
                .Url(Url.Action("ListSubData", "My"))
                .Mode(LoadMode.Script)
                .Params(new { id = Model.Id })
        });
    }))
```

My subview looks like this:

```
@model int
@{
    var x = Html.X();
}

@(x.Store(
    x.Store()
        .ID("MyDataStore")
        .AutoLoad(true)
        .Proxy(
            x.AjaxProxy()
                .Url(Url.Action("GetData", "My", new { id = Model }))
                .Reader(x.JsonReader().RootProperty("data")))
        .Model(
            x.Model()
                .Fields(
                    x.ModelField()
                        .Name("Description")
                        .Type(ModelFieldType.String),
                    x.ModelField()
                        .Name("Category")
                        .Type(ModelFieldType.String),
                    x.ModelField()
                        .Name("Id")
                        .Type(ModelFieldType.Int)))))

@(x.GridPanel()
    .ID("MyPanel")
    .StoreID("MyDataStore")
    .ColumnModel(
        x.Column()
            .DataIndex("Description")
            .Text("Name"),
        x.Column()
            .DataIndex("Category")
            .Text("Category")))
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IStoreModelFactory _myStoreModelFactory;

    public DashboardController(IStoreModelFactory factory)
    {
        _myStoreModelFactory= factory;
    }

    public ActionResult Index(MyStoreModel model)
    {
        var viewModel = new MyViewModel
        {
            Name = model.Name,
            Id = model.Id
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    public Ext.Net.MVC.PartialViewResult ListSubData(int id)
    {
        return new Ext.Net.MVC.PartialViewResult
        {
            RenderMode = RenderMode.AddTo,
            Model = id,
            ContainerId = string.Format("ListSubData_{0}", id),
            WrapByScriptTag = false
        };
    }

    public StoreResult GetData(int id)
    {
        var models = _myStoreModelFactory.GetStoreResults(id);
        return new StoreResult(models);
    }
```

I was following the example [here](http://mvc.ext.net/#/Dynamic_Partial_Rendering/Partial_Items/) but I'm not sure I'm doing it right. It looks like they're inserting the component directly onto the panel they created and insert that into the `Items` collection whereas I'm creating a `GridPanel` and inserting into another `GridPanel` but I'm not sure how to do it right in this context. How should I be doing this?

Comment: Do you have any errors in console/network?

Comment: @ZivWeissman I have no errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems in here. First is in this line:

```
ContainerId = string.Format("ListSubData_{0}", id)
```

You need element with this id on your page, so you could render your content into it. So basically, you need to change this method to:

```
public Ext.Net.MVC.PartialViewResult ListSubData(int id)
{
    return new Ext.Net.MVC.PartialViewResult
    {
        RenderMode = RenderMode.AddTo,
        Model = id,
        ContainerId = "MyContainerId",
        WrapByScriptTag = false
    };
}
```

And then change your main view to:

```
@(x.Panel()
    .ID("MyContainerId")
    .Layout(LayoutType.Fit)
    .Items(i =>
    <!-- rest of the code -->
```

The second problem is with Store on Partial View. Instead of using `.StoreID("MyDataStore")` you have to move it inside your Grid Panel like this:

```
@(x.GridPanel()
    .ID("MyPanel")
    .Store(
        x.Store()
            .ID("MyDataStore")
            .AutoLoad(true)
            <!-- rest of the code -->
```

Comment: That fixed my issue! Thank you very much!